# I want to use TimePickerPage.xaml of wp toolkit with some customization

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, toolkit, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm using **`<toolkit:TimePicker/>`** from WP Toolkit 
and it's `PickerPageUri` is set to `/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;component/DateTimePickers/TimePickerPage.xaml`

I want some customization in this page like it's background should be **White**,
text tile should be **PICK TIME** the app bar background should be **Grey**
and icons should be **Black**.

[image]

I downloaded `TimePickerPage.xaml` and `TimePickerPage.xaml.cs` so that I can quickly change its property and set it source to my new `CustomTimePickerPage.xaml` which actually contains the 99% code of `TimePickerPage.xaml`.

But it gives me errors below
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Here is the [TimePickerPage.xaml](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/DateTimePickers/TimePickerPage.xaml)

Comment: You must have changed something in the page, otherwise it wouldn't tell you that the "primitives" prefix is undeclared. The same way, the "1f1f1f" string is nowhere to be found in the original TimePickerPage.xaml page.

Comment: I have changed nothing. I'm using the the exact code but with different class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was declaring the xmlns, below is the correct way of declaring `primitives` and `controls` xmlns

```
<primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase
    x:Class="FamilyMap.CustomUIElements.CustomTimePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="728" d:DesignWidth="480">
```